# The dog falled from heaven

Tags: deathspank

I just finished Deathspank (Orphan of Justice) trying to complete all possible quests; I counted about 111 at the end.

**SPOILER**

But now I have a question. South to Lord's Castle there is a farm and there you can found a strange dog. Ima said that one day it falled from the sky.

I didn't find any way to interact with it. Am i missing something or it is just designed in that way?
Or maybe it has a role in the sequel `Thongs of Virtue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's designed that way. That dog's sole purpose is to be a creepy non sequitur.

Spoiler for Thongs of Virtue:

> While he exists in Thongs of Virtue, he doesn't have any role to play in it, either.